# Image Resize + Compression + Progressive JPEG Conversion (+ Cropping optional) All-in-One?

Tags: windows, images, image-processing, image-editor

I need to recommend software that will make it easy for a user to take an existing image and resize it (reduce dimensions), compress it, convert it to a progressive JPEG for perceived faster loading, and possibly crop it if needed.  Is there any such application available for Windows (macOS as a bonus)?

This user cannot use Photoshop or more "advanced" applications to accomplish this and thus my question since I need a consolidated easy to use app for this process.

I don't know what the actual budget is for them - I'm just trying to figure out a clean and very easy solution for them that I can recommend right now and I'm not entirely convinced anything I've seen is "clean" or sufficiently "easy"...

Answer (score 3):

[IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) is a free image-editing tool with a *many* batch-operation options, as shown below, and the JPEG save dialog includes the progressive option.

It is a Windows application, but runs well under wine in Linux (and is [available in a Snap port](https://snapcraft.io/irfanview)), so it *might* work in [wine on MacOS](https://www.winehq.org/), also.

The only possible *disadvantage* is the large number of choices, but you can pre-save settings so the user can run it by rote.

[image: IrfanView batch operations]

Comment: Hi, I've been doing automation for stuff for 20+ years. +1 for Irfanview, I've used it for 10+ years. It can do batch processing of files, but remember it will process every file in the batch the exact same way. Automated cropping can be problematic if it's more than just chopping off the outside N pixels. You might need human intervention if the cropping is different for every image.

Answer (score 1):

Give the [FastStone Image Viewer](https://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm) a try, it is always my first choice for such basic tasks. Another plus of this tool is, that it works lossless when possible.

The tool is available for free (for home users).